# 4 little exercises on transformation of random variables and convergence

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I want to know if I solved the following exercises correctly (1-3) and how nr. 4 goes. I could not finish nr. 4:

Let $U\sim \operatorname{Uni}(0,1)$ be random variable.

---

1. Let $Z=-\ln(U)$. Show that $Z\sim \operatorname{exp(\lambda)}$.

Answer: So we have $[-\ln(0)=\infty,-\ln(1)=0]$ and
$$P(-\ln(U)\leq t)=P(U\geq e^{-t})=\int\limits_{e^{-t}}^1\mathrm{d}m=1-e^{-t}\quad \text{for } t\geq 0 $$
So $\lambda = 1$

---

2. Compute $\mathbb{E}(\ln(U))$ and $\operatorname{Var}(\ln(U))$

Answer: So we have for every continuous and bounded $f$
$$\mathbb{E}(f(\ln(U)))=\int\limits_0^1 f(\ln(u))\mathrm{d}u$$
we chose $f(x)=x$ and get
$$\int\limits_{0}^1 \ln(u)\mathrm{d}u=[u\ln(u)]_0^1-\int\limits_0^1\mathrm{d}u=-1$$
we now chose $f(x)=x^2$ and get
$$\int\limits_{0}^1 (\ln(u))^2\mathrm{d}u=[u\ln(u)^2]_0^1-2\int\limits_0^1u\ln(u)\mathrm{d}u=\underbrace{[u\ln(u)^2]_0^1}_{\text{is this =0?}}+2=2$$

---

3. Let $U_1,U_2,\dots$ be a sequence of independent random variables with $U_i\sim U$. We define
   $$V_n=\prod\limits_{i=1}^n U_i$$
   Show that the sequence $V_n^{1/n}$ almost surely converges and calculate the limit.

Answer: Let $Z_n=\ln(U_n)$ then according to the law of large numbers
$$\sum\limits_0^\infty \frac{\ln(U_n)}{n}\xrightarrow{a.s.} \mathbb{E}(Z)=-1$$
So $U_n\xrightarrow{a.s.}e^{-1}$ so therefore $\sqrt[n]{V_n}\xrightarrow{a.s.}\sqrt[n]{e^{-n}}=e^{-1}$

---

4. Let $$W_n=(e^nV_n)^{1/\sqrt{n}}$$
   Show that $W_n\to W$ in distribution to a random variable $W$. Determine $W$.
   Hint: Look at $X_n=\ln(W_n)$ and write $W_n$ with $W_n=\exp(X_n)$

Answer: Let $X_n=\ln(W_n)=\ln((e^nV_n)^{1/\sqrt{n}})=-\sqrt{n}\ln(e^nV_n)$ then $$W_n=e^{-\sqrt{n}\ln(e^nV_n)}=e^{-\sqrt{n}}e^nV_n=e^{n-\sqrt{n}}V_n$$

Here I get stuck. I don't how to apply the central limit theorem here.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Re 2: Note that $f(x) = x$ and $f(x) = x^2$ are not **bounded** functions.

Comment: @saz Thanks, should it be $f(x)=x 1_{x\in [0,1]}$ and $f(x)=x^2 1_{x\in [0,1]}$?

Comment: No, because this doesn't give you the expectation and variance. The identity $$\mathbb{E}(f(\ln U)) = \int_0^1 f(\ln u) \, du$$ holds for a larger class of functions, not only for bounded functions. It holds for any function $f$ such that $\mathbb{E}(|f(\ln U)|)<\infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) is good.

2) is good but you could make it even easier.

3) is good.

4) $\log(W_n) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}(\sum \log(U_i) + n)$ and then apply CLT.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you explain me how number 2 could be made easier or atleast give me a starting point so I can do it?

Comment: You already showed that $-\log(U) \sim$ Exp($\lambda$) and you know the mean of an exponential rv : $E(\log(U))=-E(-\log(U)) = -\lambda$. The same goes for the variance.